# I want to make custom php class for custom helpers function ... is it possible in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working on the E-Commerce Application that builds on the laravel platform...
I want to check a stock of every product when I was fetching if stock not available so that will show stock isn't available on product card else show add-to-cart button. The Problem is Product cards available on different pages how can I do this ? can I make helper class function or ... please guide

this is my helper class code,

```php
use App\ProductsAttribute;
function hello($id){
   return "hello : ".$id;
}
function getStock($id){
   $c = ProductsAttribute::where('id',$id)->select('stock')->get();
   $count_stock = json_decode(json_encode($c));
   $res = $count_stock;
   return $res;
}
```

or this is my IndexController code :

```php
public function index(Request $request){

   // $productsAll = Product::paginate(12);
   $productsAll = Product::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(12)->get();

   $arrProducts = Product::inRandomOrder()->skip(0)->take(15)->get();
   $arrProducts = json_decode(json_encode($arrProducts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `app/helpers.php` file and reference it inside composer.json
After you did that you have to run the command `composer dump-autoload`

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
},
```

More info about it here: https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Comment: robin my project deploy on shared hosting how can i run coposer dump-autoload ?

Comment: If you don't have ssh access you can run it locally and re-upload the vendor folder